# Typescript import a React js component which d.ts file writed by myself and occured Module not found: Can't resolve 'xxx' in 'xxx'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, declaration

I added a component js's d.ts file as below:

```
/// <reference types="react" />

declare namespace __ReactAvatarEditor {

interface croppingRect {
    x: number,
    y: number,
    width: number,
    height: number
}

interface point {
    x: number,
    y: number
}

export interface AvatarEditorProps {
    scale?: number,
    rotate?: number,
    image?: any,
    border?: number | [number],
    borderRadius?: number,
    width?: number,
    height?: number,
    position?: point,
    color?: number[],
    style?: object,
    crossOrigin?: string,
    onDropFile?: any,
    onLoadFailure?: any,
    onLoadSuccess?: any,
    onImageReady?: any,
    onImageChange?: any,
    onMouseUp?: any,
    onMouseMove?: any,
    onPositionChange?: any,
    disableDrop?: boolean
}
export class AvatarEditor extends React.Component<AvatarEditorProps> {
}
}

declare module "react-avatar-editor"{
    export import AvatarEditorProps = __ReactAvatarEditor.AvatarEditorProps;
    export import AvatarEditor = __ReactAvatarEditor.AvatarEditor;
}
declare module "react-avatar-editor/AvatarEditor"{
    export import AvatarEditor = __ReactAvatarEditor.AvatarEditor;
    export default AvatarEditor;
}
```

And use it by:

```
import AvatarEditor from 'react-avatar-editor/AvatarEditor';
```

The Origin Code construtor:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN0Mg.png)

but while I run the project, it fail to compile and show me an error:
./src/components/DealPic.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-avatar-editor/AvatarEditor' in 'C:\Users\xiaomin\Desktop\React\inter-provincial-portrait\src\components'

Typescript v2.5.3 React v16

Comment: after I declare the class at the outside of namespace and export this class, it worked. But still has some bugs and I need to debug it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To fix it install with npm this package in this format

```
npm install --save react-avatar-editor @types/react-avatar-editor
```